# How to detect when a pagerTabStrip is selected?

Tags: android, touch, listener

With the old SwipeyTabs you could just simply use the onSwipeyTabSelected.onSwipeyTabSelected, now android released at june 2012 the PageTabStrip, which it is supossed to ease the work, and in fact it does for simple cases. But i haven't found any method that in fact allows me to detect the Selection of a tab, in example:

```
_______________________________

|          |Tab1|         Tab2|
 
_______________________________
```

if i swipe to the right and the Tab2 got selected:

```
_______________________________

|Tab1      |Tab2|         Tab3|
 
_______________________________
```

How can i detect/trigger an event in my activity containing the PagerTabStrip that this tab was selected?

P.S. Forgive me the crappy ascii art :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `PagerTabStrip` is tied to a `ViewPager`, and changes the contents of the `ViewPager`, you can register a `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` to the `ViewPager` [via `setOnPageChangeListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener%28android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener%29).

If your argument is "well, I want to do different things if they swipe via the tabs than if they swipe the body of the pager", then I'm not a fan of that UX.

Comment: I'll accept this question as it is a valid one, but it is not a listener to the PageTapStrip, or a notification from this class, but to something that actually shares the scrolling. Looks i'm stuck with this one, thank you anyway!

Comment: @desgraci: Well, since they scroll in unison, the difference is largely semantic IMHO. You could always clone the `PagerTabStrip` code and look to add your own listener mechanism to your fork of it.

Comment: Yeah, it was more like the case when you want to overwrite the default listener, and separate it from the tabs (not recommended), but well then, that's why i'm going to hell..., anyway, there's any real advantage with the PagerTabStrip over the SwipeyTabs, or it is just the google code updates?

Comment: @desgraci: Well, I'm not really sure which "SwipeyTabs" you're referring to. If you mean action bar tabs, they have the advantage of not needing to work with a `ViewPager`. If you mean the tabs from ViewPagerIndicator, I haven't tried those. And if you mean something else, I'm lost. :-)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/, but it is kinda incomplete, not sure how it is called now to be honest, cause i think is a fusion of action bar tabs, tabsadapter and ofc the viewpager :D